# Three stage nested design with repeated sampling

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, experiment-design, nested-models

**My experimental design is similar to that from a classic study of metal alloy hardness.**

The classic example:

*A researcher designs an experiment to study the hardness of a metal alloy. A three-stage nested design was conducted that included:*

- Two alloy chemistry compositions.
- Three ovens for each alloy chemistry composition (6 ovens were used).
- Four ingot molds were used to produce alloy ingots for each of the six combinations of alloy chemistry composition and oven (24 molds were used).
- Three ingots were produced from each of the 24 molds.

**Here is where my design differs from the classic example:**

- Each of the 24 molds were sampled four times, and at each time point, three ingots were produced and the hardness was measured.

I'm planning on using `lme4` to analyze my data, **but I'm unsure how to set up the random effects structure.** In my example, alloy chemistry is a fixed effect, oven is a random effect and (I think) mold is also a random effect. Mold is sampled over time and there are three subsamples (ingots) within each time point.

I also have explanatory variables about the mold that I would like to include. I'll call these "explanatory1" and "explanatory2"

My current best guess at model set up:

```
hardness ~ alloy*Time + explanatory1 + explanatory2 + (1|oven/mold/ingot)
```

or

```
hardness ~ alloy + explanatory1 + explanatory2 + (1|oven/mold/ingot x Time)
```